# Rails: nested join queries with polymorphic associations and custom class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Consider the following example of a school. There is a classroom (chosen over the term 'class' to avoid any syntactic confusions). Each classroom has many students and one prefect, who is one among those students. Shown below is how I have written the models:

```rb
class Classroom
    has_many :students, inverse_of: :classroom
    belongs_to :prefect, class_name: "Student", inverse_of: :classroom
end

class Student
    belongs_to :classroom, inverse_of: :students
    belongs_to :house, inverse_of: :members
end

class House
    has_many :members, class_name: "Student", inverse_of: :house, foreign_key: "house_id"
    has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address
    # attribute city: :string
    belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The purpose of house is to track students who come from the same house. Each house has an address and one of the attributes of address is `city`. Of course there are other attributes in each of these models that I have not mentioned for brevity. `Address`, for instance, belongs to other models that are not listed here, hence the polymorphic association.

**Objective**

My objective is to get the list of classrooms whose prefects are from a particular city. I know there are ways to solve this in Ruby, but how can I achieve this using an ActiveRecord/SQL query? I'm using Rails 5.0 and Postgres 9.6.

**What I Have Tried**

I have already tried a couple of ways, all by joining the tables up. However, the issue I face is that due to the unconventional names, AR is unable to generate the apt query. Here's the most promising variation of what I tried:

```rb
Classroom.joins(prefect: {house: :address}).where(prefect: {house: {address: {city: "Barcelona"}}})
```

The join seems to be working fine. However, the `where` bit goes bonkers since the underlying table for prefect is `students`. The result of running this is just an ActiveRecord Relation object. But run `.to_a` on that and I get the following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "address"
```

I was successfully able to retrieve classrooms whose prefects have a particular first name as follows:

```rb
Classroom.joins(prefect: {house: :address}).where(students: {first_name: "Juliana"})
```

But that's the best I got. I'm not able to apply the same logic when the nesting comes in:

```rb
Classroom.joins(prefect: {house: :address}).where(students: {house: {address: {city: "Barcelona"}}})
```

Running this one results in the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `_reflect_on_association' for nil:NilClass
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@school/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/table_metadata.rb:47:in `associated_table'
```

Any ideas what I should do here?

Comment: This is a good question but I think it needs a better title to describe the situation so it can be found by others with similar problems. Something along the lines of "Rails: nested join queries with polymorphic associations"

Comment: Oh yeah! Good suggestion. I'll go ahead and change that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Classroom.joins(prefect: {house: :address}).where(prefects: { houses: { addresses: { city: "Barcelona"}}})
```

Side note: I think you're overusing `:inverse_of`. From the Rails guides

> Active Record supports automatic identification for most associations
>   with standard names. However, Active Record will not automatically
>   identify bi-directional associations that contain any of the following
>   options:

- > :conditions
- > :through
- > :polymorphic
- > :class_name
- > :foreign_key

and

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, inverse_of: 'writer'
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'Author', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

So you can simplify your models a bit to this

```
class Classroom
  has_many :students
  belongs_to :prefect, class_name: "Student"
end

class Student
  belongs_to :classroom
  belongs_to :house, inverse_of: :members
end

class House
  has_many :members, class_name: "Student", foreign_key: "house_id"
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: @m-simon-borg I am still debating about what's the better association here. From one angle, it seems fine for the student record to have knowledge about whether it is a prefect or not. But on the other hand, that detail is something that's closely associated with the classroom rather than the student. This was why I chose the current approach.

Comment: @Jerry but is the classroom able to find it's prefect without a foreign key to match?

Comment: Oops! Looks like I made a mistake in the original snippet. I'll be honest, the models are not what I actually have. They're just equivalents I chose, and I just realized that it probably wasn't the best analogy.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet now. The association in classroom is `belongs_to :prefect...` which I know doesn't make sense from the context of a classroom, but it's an identical representation of my modelling where that association actually makes sense.

Comment: ok, does the updated query at the top of the answer work now? @Jerry

Comment: Just tried now, but unfortunately it didn't work. Got the same error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `_reflect_on_association' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: is the posted code complete now? is there a prefect_id foreign key to find the prefect? i think it would be helpful to see the schema and associations as accurately as possible

Comment: Yes, it's complete. There is a `prefect_id` in classroom.

Comment: Btw, thanks a lot for your assistance - really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Jerry No problem! I should tell you that the query is working for me when I reproduce your setup given all the information you've provided (my models look like the examples I posted above with less use of `inverse_of`).

Comment: Hmm, this is quite strange. I'm still facing the same issue. When I change the keys in the `where` section to their singular forms, I get an active record relation object, but the query hasn't really run and invoking `to_a` results in the same exception as the one I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I'm trying to see if I've missed anything in the question.

Comment: The only thing I can see is if, for instance, I replaced the Student model with a more generic model like Person and students being people fall under that bucket. The associations would still use the name `students`, but they really are `people`. Would your query work for this scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151496/discussion-between-jerry-and-m-simon-borg).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that worked for me, and it's much simpler than what I originally tried:

```ruby
Classroom.joins(prefect: {house: :address}).where("addresses.city = ?", "Barcelona")
```